# How to display a gcm push notification on the lock screen?

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send push notification to my android device and place them such that it is hard for the user to miss the push notification. Especially if the app is not running or is in background. I already know how to handle gcm push notification while the app is running. However, I am interested in how to customly display gcm message if the app is not running.

This is the situation I have right now:

- App is closed/not running
- I send a push notification with my python script and it is recieved on my device
- A sound is played the screen keeps dark, no vibration
- When hitting the sleep/wake button I can see a small notification

This is what I want:

1. App is closed/not running, device is locked, screen is off
2. I send a push notification via gcm to my device
3. when the message is recieved by my the device the following should happen

   - Phone should vibrate
   - Phone screen should turn on and show a custom notification
   - Phone should play a sound (okay, that already works)

After an extensive search on the net I have not found any resource yet that explains how to do that.

Can anybody provide a some guidance to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` which prevents phone from sleeping and check GCM notification even if your app is not open.

Below are steps to achieve so

**STEP-1  :** You've to add `WAKE_LOCK`, `INTERNET` and other permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

**STEP-2  :** Register `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and `GCMMessageHandler` also in manifest file under `<application>` tag

```
<receiver android:name=".gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        <category android:name="com.hmkcode.android.gcm"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name=".gcm.GcmMessageHandler"/>
```

**STEP-3  :** Definition for `GcmBroadcastReceiver` is below

```
package your.package.name.gcm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmMessageHandler.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }

}
```

**STEP-4  :** Definition of `GcmMessageHandler` is

```
package your.package.name.gcm;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import your.package.name.R;
import your.package.name.SplashScreen;

public class GcmMessageHandler  extends IntentService {

    public GcmMessageHandler() {
        super("GcmMessageHandler");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        if(!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                Log.e("GCM", "Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                Log.e("GCM", "Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification(extras);
            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(Bundle extras) {
        try {
            String message = extras.getString("message");
            if(message != null) {
                Log.e(tag, "Notification received " + message);
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                mBuilder.setContentTitle("TITLE");
                mBuilder.setContentText(message);
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL); // this line sets the default vibration and sound for notification
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
            } else {
                Log.d(tag, "Message is empty.");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(tag, Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
        }
    }

}
```

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Great answer thanks. I will implement this in the next days and mark it as "Answered" when I am done.

Comment: Yeah, I tested it. Exactly what I wanted and works perfectly fine. Thanks man!